# com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView - error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml, facebook

Yes I have this error at the

```
<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
```

line and **this is a question that has been asked numerous times on stackoverflow, and every time it seems it has been fixed by adding xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" at the top. Well that didnt solve it for me**, dont know why :( So what do I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/selection_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:is_cropped="true"
        facebook:preset_size="small" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried

```
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture"
```

but didnt work as well

This is my project.properties file:

```
target=android-18
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=..\\actionbarsherlock
android.library.reference.2=..\\library
android.library.reference.3=../facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0/facebook
```

tried changing it to

```
target=android-18
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=..\\actionbarsherlock
android.library.reference.2=..\\library
android.library.reference.3=..\\facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0\facebook
```

but no results either

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your XML.

1) you have not declared the namespace "app"

2) you have declared the namespace **xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** but you are refering it as "facebook" i.e. facebook:preset_size

you can fix this by

1) Adding a namespace declaration for "app" i.e. **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**

2) renaming your "fb" namespace declaration to "facebook" i.e. **xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I just copied this over from facebooks sdk tutorial so Im a bit disappointed. I have to admit I dont know what is the "app" declaration for... Will accept the answer as soon as I can

Comment: BTW why do you think my project.properties file had the slashes in both directions in its initial state?

Comment: oh I got it. In order to use the app:is_cropped property, I needed to tell XML where to get its definition from