# how to add a facebook namespace to android project?

Tags: java, android, facebook, namespaces

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize, facebook says that to resolve the to resolve the custom view unrecognized error, you have to add a facebook namespace based on the current package? I tried looking it up but couldn't find anything. Do you do it in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked hard but I think I found the answer for this question. If anyone else has question, reroute it to this [com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView - error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593245/com-facebook-widget-profilepictureview-error-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefi)